# Deep Insert using wcf data services client library / odata

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

We are planning to do deep insert below is the code for it. Its not working can somebody help me.

```
Order orderObj = new Order

OrderDetail oDetailObj = new OrderDetail 

context.AttachTo(Orders, orderObj);

Code to set properties of orderObj 

for loop to add orders details
{

Code to set properties of oDetailObj 

context.AddRelatedObject(orderObj, "OrderDetailsList", oDetailObj); 

}
```

Comment: Is this Entity Framework -> `context`?

Comment: What isnt working? do you have an error message?

Comment: @DonA...It is data service context (using wcf data service client library)

Comment: @Robesz...I have seen in the fiddler it is not generating atompub xml for child object (order details). Atompub xml is only available for parent object (order)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do deep insert using DataServiceContext is to use Batch mode. While the OData protocol supports deep insert, DataServiceContext does not have that support in it.

For doing Batch, call ctx.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch)

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: Can it possible through...IOdataRequestMessage ?